# Derivative from the left and right

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am currently trying to write a script that takes a curve $C$, a starting point $p$ and a direction vector $\vec{v}$ and calculates the path of a beam starting at $p$ in direction $\vec{v}$ when it is reflected on $C$.

The idea is basically: (Numerically) find the (first) crossing point of beam and $C$, calculate tangent in that point, calculate new beam direction, repeat.

Now, if my curve is point-wise not differentiable (in my case: $C$ has "kinks"), I would like to treat it as a limit case where both smooth curves around the kinks are considered, so the calculation forks and I get 2 possible beam pathes.
For this, I need the left and the right side derivative of this point. How do I get those in Mathematica?

Also, if somebody knows a better way or this has already been written and is public, I appreciate any clues, of course.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `NumericalCalculus` Package already treats this:

> Use `Scale` to specify directional derivatives.

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
f[x_] := TriangleWave[x];
ND[f[x], {x, 1}, 3/4, Scale -> -1]
ND[f[x], {x, 1}, 3/4, Scale -> 1]
(*
-> -3.99999
    3.99999
*)
```

Comment: One should of course give the usual caveat of numerical differentiation being somewhat unstable, so some care is necessary if using this method.

Comment: @J.M. The problem is that Mma treats numerically some functions it shouldn't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326110/a-curious-plot-with-integerpartx

Comment: Great, I thought so :) My functions are not two crazy, mostly piecewise defined straight lines or short polynominals, so both ways should work just fine.

Answer (score 10):

If your kinked curve is a function that is known to *Mathematica* or is entirely in terms of functions known to *Mathematica*, you can go back to using the definition of left and right derivatives, and use `Limit[]` for the purpose, along with its `Direction` option:

```
Plot[TriangleWave[x], {x, 0, 2},
     Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{1/4, TriangleWave[1/4]}]}]
```

[image: triangle wave example]

```
(* coming from the left *)
Limit[(TriangleWave[1/4 + h] - TriangleWave[1/4])/h, h -> 0, Direction -> 1]
4

(* coming from the right *)
Limit[(TriangleWave[1/4 + h] - TriangleWave[1/4])/h, h -> 0, Direction -> -1]
-4
```

If your function is an `InterpolatingFunction[]` or some other black-box  function that can only take numerical arguments, different approaches are needed. If that's what you're interested in, I'll edit this answer later for a possible strategy for those.

Comment: I think this should do the trick, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you write just simply `Limit[TriangleWave'[1/4 + eps], eps -> 0, Direction -> #] & /@ {1, -1}` returning `{4, -4}` ?

Comment: @Artes: I didn't want to have to evaluate `TriangleWave'`? Besides, I wanted OP to see that the textbook definition is usable here...