# Differentiating a Cumulative Distribution Function which has a discontinuity at $0$

Tags: plotting, differentials

I want to take the derivative of a distribution function which has a discontinuity at $0$. Here is the function:

```
temp0[x_] :=If[Element[x, Reals], Sqrt[Pi]*(Erfc[(-2 + Log[2])/(2*Sqrt[2])] + (1 + Erf[(1 +Piecewise[{{(x - Log[2])/2, x < 0}}, (x + Log[2])/2])/Sqrt[2]] - Erfc[(-2 + Log[2])/(2*Sqrt[2])])*UnitStep[-Log[2]/2 - Piecewise[{{(x - Log[2])/2, x < 0}}, (x + Log[2])/2]]) + Sqrt[(2*Pi)/E]*(Erf[Log[2]/(2*Sqrt[2])] - Erf[Piecewise[{{(x - Log[2])/2, x < 0}}, (x + Log[2])/2]/Sqrt[2]])*UnitStep[-Log[2]/2 + Piecewise[{{(x - Log[2])/2, x < 0}}, (x + Log[2])/2]] + 2*Sqrt[Pi]*(-Erf[(2 + Log[2])/(2*Sqrt[2])] + Erf[(1 + Piecewise[{{(x - Log[2])/2, x < 0}}, (x + Log[2])/2])/Sqrt[2]])*UnitStep[-Log[2]/2 + Piecewise[{{(x - Log[2])/2, x < 0}}, (x + Log[2])/2]] + Sqrt[(2*Pi)/E]*(Erf[Log[2]/(2*Sqrt[2])] + Erf[Piecewise[{{(x - Log[2])/2, x < 0}}, (x + Log[2])/2]/Sqrt[2]])*UnitStep[Log[2]/2 + Piecewise[{{(x - Log[2])/2, x < 0}}, (x + Log[2])/2]], Integrate[(Sqrt[2]*UnitStep[-y - Log[2]/2] + 2*((Sqrt[2] - E^y)*UnitStep[y - Log[2]/2] + E^y*UnitStep[y + Log[2]/2]))/E^((1 + y)^2/2), {y, -Infinity, Piecewise[{{(x - Log[2])/2, x < 0}, {(x + Log[2])/2, x >= 0}}, 0]}, Assumptions -> NotElement[x, Reals]]]/(Sqrt[Pi]*(2*Sqrt[2/E]*Erf[Log[2]/(2*Sqrt[2])] + Erfc[(-2 + Log[2])/(2*Sqrt[2])] + 2*Erfc[(2 + Log[2])/(2*Sqrt[2])]))
```

If I plot it I get

[image]

The result of the derivation should be a density function. I used

```
fx0[x_] := D[temp0[x], x]
```

to get the density function but it didnt help me. Do you know how can I ignore the discontinuity at $0$ for the derivation?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition of `temp0[x]`, it is possible to plot the derivative by taking the limit:

```
der[x_] := Limit[temp0'[x + eps], eps -> 0];
Plot[der[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Note the kink at the origin. This uses a similar technique to J. M.'s answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6402/1783).

Answer (score 4):

> OP wrote: Do you know how can I ignore the discontinuity at 0 for the derivation?

You most definitely do not want to 'ignore' the discontinuity at 0. The fact that the CDF jumps from about 0.64 to about 0.84 at $x = 0$ implies that your density is:

- piecewise continuous for $x < 0$,
- has a discrete mass at $x = 0$, *i.e.* $f(0) \approx 0.2$, and then
- piecewise continuous for $x>0$.

The density should thus appear like so:

[image]

You can plot the discrete mass at $x = 0$ using something like:

`BB = ListPlot[{{0, .2}}, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[8], Filling -> Axis]`

and then:

```
Show[AA,BB]
```

where `AA` is the continuous plot ... to get the complete mixed continuous/discrete density.

Comment: thanks for the post and for the information. You are exactly right, in fact. I get the distribution function via transformation temp0[x_] := ff0[ll[x]] here ll[x] is the inverse function of Piecewise[{{{0}, -Log[2]/2 <= x <= Log[2]/2}, {Log[E^(2*x)/2], 2*x > Log[2]}}, Log[2*E^(2*x)]]  and ff0[x] is the CDF of the density (UnitStep[-x - Log[2]/2]/(E^((1 + x)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi]) + (Sqrt[2/Pi]*UnitStep[x - Log[2]/2])/E^((1 + x)^2/2) + 
  (Sqrt[E^(-(-1 + x)^2/2)]*Sqrt[E^(-(1 + x)^2/2)]*(-UnitStep[x - Log[2]/2] + UnitStep[x + Log[2]/2]))/Sqrt[Pi])/C1  I simply took ll[0]=Log[2]/2 which is originally

Comment: My density doesnt add upto $1$ when I ignore the point pass. How can I modify my function at $0$?

Comment: I have no idea whether it is appropriate for you to ignore the discrete point ... but if the mass at $x = 0$ is `p`, and you _want_ to ignore the point at $x = 0$ (??), and the continuous component of your pdf is `f`, then `f/(1-p)` should be a well-defined density that integrates to unity (with the discrete point expunged).

Comment: I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose the mixture distribution using `ProbabilityDistirbution` (suppressing some error messages):

```
md = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", temp0[x]}, {x, -Infinity, 
     Infinity}] // Quiet;
Show[Plot[md[[1, 1]] md[[2, 1, 1]] /. \[FormalX] -> x, {x, -10, 10}], 
 DiscretePlot[
  md[[1, 2]] md[[2, 2, 1]] /. \[FormalX] -> x, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}], PlotRange -> {0, 0.3}]
```

[image]