# Why doesn't AsymptoticIntegrate work?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following asymptotic

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]
```

fails in 13.3 on Windows 10, returning the input. However, the following

```
Assuming[n >= 3, AsymptoticIntegrate[ Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]]
```

> `1/(6 n) + 1/(5 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n]) - (2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n])/3 - n + ( n^2 \[Pi])/4`

works well. What is the reason of it? I don't find any explanation in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticIntegrate.html?q=AsymptoticIntegrate).

Comment: `AsymptoticIntegrate[Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]` also fails.

Comment: The @Nasser's answer  does not explain why `AsymptoticIntegrate[Sqrt[n - k], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]` works well, producing `-(2/3) + 1/(4 Sqrt[n]) - Sqrt[n] + (2 n^(3/2))/3`

Comment: I'm waiting for a rich-in-content answer.

Comment: I'd like to add that `Assuming[n >= - 30, 
 AsymptoticIntegrate[ 
  Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]]` performs `1/(6 n) + 1/(5 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n]) - (2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n])/3 - n + (
 n^2 \[Pi])/4` .

Answer (score 5):

It seems because Integrate itself needs to know `n` is in integer domain.

Compare

```
Integrate[Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}]
```

Which does not evaluate, with

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers],  Integrate[Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}]]
```

Which evaluates giving

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hence your command becomes now

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers], 
   AsymptoticIntegrate[Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

V 14

Comment: Sorry, your attempt of the explanation is somewhat light-weighted: (i) `Assuming[Element[n, PositiveReals],   AsymptoticIntegrate[   Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]]` works well; (ii) `Integrate[Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, GenerateConditions -> False]` performs `1/2 ((-1 + n) Sqrt[-1 + 2 n] - Sqrt[-1 + n^2] +     n^2 ArcTan[(-1 + n)/Sqrt[-1 + 2 n]] - n^2 ArcTan[1/Sqrt[-1 + n^2]])`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Moreover, even `Assuming[Element[n, Reals], 
 AsymptoticIntegrate[
  Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]]` and `Assuming[Element[n, Reals], 
 AsymptoticIntegrate[
  Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, -Infinity, 1}]]` work.

Comment: @user64494 OK, then use `Assuming[Element[n, Reals]`. Basically the issue is that Integrate needed to know it is not complex. I used `Integers` and found it to work. If `Reals` works, it leads to same conclusion. Integrate needed to know what domain `n` is in,. Did you really had to down vote me just for this?

Comment: Did you carefully read my comment? I repeat that `Integrate[Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, GenerateConditions -> False]` without any assumptions performs `1/2 ((-1 + n) Sqrt[-1 + 2 n] - Sqrt[-1 + n^2] +     n^2 ArcTan[(-1 + n)/Sqrt[-1 + 2 n]] - n^2 ArcTan[1/Sqrt[-1 + n^2]])` and then `Series[%,{n,Infinity,1}` does the work.

Comment: @user64494 that is because when you add `GenerateConditions -> False` you are bypassing the code that caused it not to evaluate when no domain is given. It was hanging in the code which you told it not to evaluate. It is well know that  `GenerateConditions -> False` can make many integrals not hang when they will otherwise will, since the default is  `GenerateConditions -> True`. Of if they not hang, they will evaluate much faster when adding `GenerateConditions -> False`

Comment: Sorry, I prefer formulas and arguments over ungrounded statements.

Comment: @user64494 you want me to give a formula for saying that `GenerateConditions->True`  can cause much more code to be evaluated and can sometime lead to hangs or slower evaluation? I've seen this many times. May be search can show some examples. But I have no time now to search for examples. But you can see this  as reference [what-exactly-does-generateconditions-do](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/what-exactly-does-generateconditions-do)

Comment: From above by Daniel Lichtblau himself:  **GenerateConditions -> False will both skip some code for checking parameter regions of validity for an integral, and also a regularized integral might be computed**  And **so defaulting to True at all levels might keep many inputs from running to completion.**

Comment: Nasser (@ does not work): Sorry, your answer does not explain why `AsymptoticIntegrate[Sqrt[n - k], {k, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]` works well, producing `-(2/3) + 1/(4 Sqrt[n]) - Sqrt[n] + (2 n^(3/2))/3`. I will be waiting for a rich-in-content answer.

Comment: BTW, `Integrate[Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]` is running without any response in a fresh kernel on my comp during  a half an hour. PS. At last, it produces `ConditionalExpression[
 1/2 (-Sqrt[-1 + 2 n] + n Sqrt[-1 + 2 n] - Sqrt[-1 + n^2] + 
    n^2 (-ArcCsc[n] + ArcSin[(-1 + n)/n])), Re[n] > 2 && Im[n] == 0]`.

Comment: It's interesting that `Integrate[Sqrt[n^2 - k^2], {k, 1, n - 1}]` results in `ConditionalExpression[
 1/2 ((-1 + n) Sqrt[-1 + 2 n] - Sqrt[-1 + n^2] + 
    n^2 ArcTan[(-1 + n)/Sqrt[-1 + 2 n]] - 
    n^2 ArcTan[1/Sqrt[-1 + n^2]]), 
]`.

Comment: `3 + (6 + 4 Sqrt[3]) Im[n]^2 + 2 Sqrt[3] Re[n] <= 
   2 (3 + 2 Sqrt[3]) Re[n]^2 && ((-1 + n)/(-2 + n) \[NotElement] 
     Reals || 
    Re[(-1 + n)/(-2 + n)] < 
     0 || ((Re[(-1 + n)/(-2 + n)] >= 1 || 
        Re[(-1 + n)/(-2 + n)] <= 0) && ((
         1 - n)/(-2 + n) \[NotElement] Reals || 
        Re[(1 - n)/(-2 + n)] < -1))) && ((1 + n)/(
     2 - n) \[NotElement] Reals || 
    Re[(1 + n)/(2 - n)] < 
     0 || ((Re[(1 + n)/(2 - n)] >= 1 || 
        Re[(1 + n)/(2 - n)] <= 0) && ((1 + n)/(-2 + n) \[NotElement] 
         Reals || Re[(1 + n)/(-2 + n)] < -1)))`

Comment: @user64494, there is no space after @. It automatically shows you what to autocomplete. Anyway, does the Integral make sense for Complex? I mean, it is clearly defaulting to Complex by default, be it variables or method of integrating. Remember this funny thing that is an exception: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272799/82985

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников:  Sorry, all that is off-topic. Thank you anyway.